# Getting current cursor position in EditText

Tags: java, kotlin, android-edittext

Trying to get current cursor position in my editText in Android. Didn't find any solution. Simply can't get cursor position but can set position.
Now trying to set cursor in `onTextChanged` function like below:

```
private var prevValue = ""

override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        prevValue = s.toString()
    }

override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (count - before > 1) {
            val newPos= s!!.length- abs(start-prevValue.length) 
            // newPos is incorrect. How can I calculate current cursor position?
            editText.setSelection(min(max(0,newPos),formattedValue.length))
            //I want to set cursor on the position where user typed any symbol

        }
    }
```

Any advices or help?

Comment: getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd return 0 because I'm not selecting text in EditText.

Comment: According to the answer I've linked, `getSelectionStart` returns the cursor position if no text is selected, is this not what you've found?

Comment: It returns 0 in any case :(

Comment: @HenryTwist Oops, update. It returns position when my cursor in the end, but I need position in other cases

Comment: Strange. Can you update your question with what you've tried?